# Problema con la extensión live server en visual studio code

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo el problema que no puedo hacer funcionar la extensión live server. Probé des instalar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]y volver a instalar visual studio code y sigue sin funcionar. Probé con una computadora de escritorio (con Windows 10) y una notebook (con Windows 11). Probé descargar la última versión de visual studio code.
La extensión se instala bien pero no me muestra la opción para abrirla. Los archivos que quiero hacer que me muestren son un archivo index.html y style.css. Lo que veo raro es que no me aparece la opción para habilitar la extensión solo des instalar y volver a instalar.
No se si saben de alguna otra extensión que haga algo similar.
Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

Comment: pero.. la activaste?

Comment: Amigo donde lo activo? Porque en la página de live server que me abre pero me da la opción de des instalar o instalar.

Comment: en tu imagen se ve "esta extension esta desactivada porque el espacio de trabajo no es de confianza"... y me hiciste copiar todo el texto.. tu espacio de trabajo, es de confianza??? si no, busca en google que quiere decir, y arreglalo.... y lee los mensajes ;)

Comment: Amigo lo pude solucionar! Te agradezco la ayuda! Soy nuevo en esto y recién estoy empezando. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Amigo como hago para para marcar la pregunta como ya está resuelta?

Comment: No puede estar resuelta porque no tiene respuestas (Esto son comentarios, no respuestas!). Una pregunta sin respuesta jamás estará resuelta. Ve a la parte de abajo donde dice "Tu Respuesta", explica lo que hiciste para solucionarlo y luego puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada, que es lo que indica que una pregunta ya tiene solución

Comment: Leiste el [tour].. obviamente no lo entendiste o lo pasaste por arriba... leelo de vuelta, y entende como funciona el sitio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione activando el espacio de trabajo para que sea de confianza. Muchas gracias a todos los que comentaron mi pregunta y me ayudaron a resolver el problema que tenía.